# Outlook - MS Graph API - how to check Room Sharing options?

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, office365, outlook-restapi

I am building a REST integration using MS Graph 1.0.
I am basically creating Room bookings using the createEvent API and this works just fine.

Now as I understand, some Rooms can be private, meaning only shared with specific Users or Groups. How can I check that using MS Graph? Is there a dedicated API for this? O rmaybe at least you can point me to the relevant object/property I should be looking into?

I want to check if the user triggering the integration is one of the users/groups allowed to book that Room and only then create the invite for that room.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking in to places API room resource type, it has bookingType property which says whether the room is standard/reserved. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/room?view=graph-rest-beta#bookingtype-values.

Comment: Hi, thanks but I think I need to check something slightly different... I would like to check if there is some setting that allows e.g. only "CEO" group to book a specific "CEO meeting room" etc. I know something liek this can be set up in Outlook but not sure where to look for the USer/Group/Resource sharing relationships...